# How to get file name and its full path with PHP using scandir

Tags: php

I want to print file name and its full path of files in a folder and sub-folders also.
My Code:

```
function listFolderFiles($dir){
    $ffs = scandir($dir);
    echo '<ol>';
    foreach($ffs as $ff){
        if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
            echo '<li>'.$ff;
            if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
            echo '</li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ol>';
}

listFolderFiles('Main Dir');
```

But it is only printing the file name not the path.

Comment: You may want to looking into a `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`: http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php

Comment: thanks Rasclatt i found the solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
function listFolderFiles($dir){
    $ffs = scandir($dir);
    echo '<ol>';
    foreach($ffs as $ff){
        if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
            echo '<li>'.$ff;
            echo "   Real Path: ". $dir.'/'.$ff;
            if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) 
                    listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
            echo '</li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ol>';
}

listFolderFiles('/var/www/TestFiles');
```

Answer (score 0):

check out [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php):

```
  echo '<li>'.$ff ." and full path is ". realpath($ff) . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: it gives full path of your file, what else you want

Comment: but after replacing my code with your's, it is neither printing anything nor giving any error.

Comment: did you changed it in loop

Comment: Yes i replaced "echo '<li>'.$ff;" with "echo '<li>'.$ff ." and full path is ". realpath($ff) . PHP_EOL;", but it is only printing the filename and the string "and full path is" nothing else.

Comment: what is your php version ?, because this is working for me

Comment: m using PHP Version 5.4.24